# Is my rescued budgie healthy?

Tags: health, birds, play, cage, budgerigar

We just had a new budgie, got it from my parents. Main reason we decided to adopt him is because he's been bullied by his mates in cage (there's like 8 of them on a regular sized cage).

As for my mom, they've been chasing him until he's beak bleed a little, he's been sleeping only on the bottom side of the cage because he's inferior on the bunch. He's got a missing toenail as well and slightly cracked beak. When we got him, he runs fast away from our hands (as expected) but never bites once we put him on our hands or display our fingers. He's 3 yrs old I think.

Just a concern on how to gain his trust and to check some of his symptoms like whenever he sleeps, he does some sound like snoring, is it normal? We also have an existing 6 month old budgie and they've been seeing each other for a week now with separate cages and it looks promising. Want to know as well if my 6m old budgie is just being playful by walking near him and pecking his beak a little then moving away then doing it again. Our adopted budgie kinda ignores him lol. I am not hearing any hissing sound when they're together only the approach, moves around, peck a little then move out.

Here's a vid of them
[Budgie](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10Wm7V4if0tm3AxpvgWHCtOABjTgsuZz6/view?usp=drivesdk)

Update:

He has new behavior where his head kinda spins and he tries to revert it back, hard to explain but it's like a disk jockey spinning the disk back and forth but slower.

We think that he is blind as well, he flies but always bumps straight unto something, falls over tables when walking. I tried shocking him with my hand but he wouldn't budge.

My question is, based on the said behaviors. Should I be concerned over his health, is it normal on some or is it sign of dying?

Comment: Please, what exactly is your question? If the question is formulated in a clear manner, it is much more easy for you to get answers :)

Comment: @Allerleirauh Oh, sorry. Will make some edit, thanks!

Comment: If you think the behavior of the new budgie can be explained with it's blindness, then you can explain this in answering your own question. This is allowed and even encouraged here to help others interested in or even having the same as your question